# How to make a specific type of illustration in overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to know how to create a illustration like the one below with LaTeX. Can anyone help me?[image]

Comment: Welcome to teX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with Overleaf, so we've removed that tag.  The tag we've added: "tikz-pgf" would be a good way to start learning how to create the illustration that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I am new on stackexchange and try to do my best to understand how this site works both technically and culturally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are novice in latex and here, let me make an exception ;-)

Something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 11mm,
arr/.style = {draw=blue!70!black, -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, very thick},
  N/.style = {font=\small, text width=54mm, align=center, inner sep=2pt},
                        ]
% left image
\node (n1) [N]  {Set \mbox{$r_1=0$}\\
                 Use fixed window $[0,r_2]$};
\draw[thick]    (n1.west) -- ++ (0,-24mm)
                (n1.east) -- ++ (0,-24mm);
                %
\coordinate[below=19mm of n1.west] (aux1);
\path[arr]  (n1.east |- aux1) node[right] {$r_2$} --
            (aux1) node[left] {$1_2$};
% right image
\node (n2) [N, right=of n1]  
                {Set \mbox{$r\in[0,r_1-r_2]$}\\
                 Use fixed termination window $[r_1,r_2]$};
\draw[thick]    (n2.west) -- ++ (0,-24mm)
                (n2.east) -- ++ (0,-24mm);
                %
\coordinate[below=19mm of n2.west] (aux2);
\coordinate[above=of aux2] (aux3);
\coordinate[above=of aux3] (aux4);
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux2) --
            (aux2) node[left] {$r_1$};
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux3) node[right] {$r_2$} -- ++ 
            (-36mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
\path[arr]  (n2.east |- aux4) -- node[above] {$r_w=r_2-r_1$} ++
            (-24mm,0) node[left] {$r_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For code details, please read Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, at least chapter **2 Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students** (page 31) and than **Part III Ti*k*Z ist *kein* Zeichenprogramm** (page 123).

Comment: I am impressed.
I dont know how to thank you!

Comment: Is this your first exception ?

Comment: @BlackMild, no :-).